# node loopback updateAll update property with another property value

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm trying to call a node loopback updateAll method where one property receives the value of another property. How I do this?

```
Model.updateAll(
     {
       Status: 'Cancel',
      },
      {
        Qty: 0
        QtyCancelled: Qty   <------------- How I should write this line?
      },
     function(err, info) {
      console.log('result',info);
     }
  );

}
```

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LoopBack does not supports updates where one property receives a value read from the database and/or other properties in the update command.

If you are using an SQL database, then you can run an SQL query directly.

```
Model.dataSource.connector.execute(
  'UPDATE Model SET Qty=?, QtyCancelled=Qty WHERE Status = "Cancel"',
  [0],
  function (err, info) {
    // ...
  });
```

See https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Executing-native-SQL.html

Many of no-SQL connectors support `execute` API too, please check the documentation of the connector you are using.

Comment: You are welcome, I am happy to help. Would you mind upvoting my answer?